# Node.js: error when trying to listen to a variable set to dynamic function

Tags: javascript, node.js

First off, apologies for my lack of knowledge with node, I'm probably making some big noob mistakes. In the following example I'm trying to set a variable to a function that has a continuously changing output, listen for a change in that variable, and output the new results whenever the value of the variable changes. This is the following error that I'm receiving and I don't have a clue what to do about it.

```
cli.js:15
result.on('data', function(data) {
       ^
TypeError: Object function () {
    runCommand('watch','-n1 ps -ef | grep node');
} has no method 'on'
```

Here is my example code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function runCommand(arg1,arg2) {
    var cmd = spawn(arg1,[arg2]);
    cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        return data;
    });
}

var result = function() {
    runCommand('watch','-n1 ps -ef | grep node');
}

result.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I'm running this on a Linux build.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning data from `.on('data'..`, you should log the results. This should not actually return anything, since it's an [async callback](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html).

Also, you do not need to create function to use `runCommand`, just call the method somewhere in the code. You will also need to note that `-n1` and `ps -ef | grep node` should be separate arguments.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// Add a callback argument to runCommand.
function runCommand(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // Remove the [] around arg2.
    var cmd = spawn(arg1,arg2);
    cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', callback);
}

// Instead of passing one long string as arg2, use an array to pass each argument.
runCommand('watch', [  '-n1', 'ps -ef | grep node' ], function (data) {
    // Log the output in the callback.
    console.log('Data received: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: In the bigger application I'm creating I need to be able to monitor the output of the runCommand function and fire other functions off  based on the new data after it's changed. That's why I'm trying to figure out a way to monitor the spawn command the way I am.

Comment: @Brad.Smith, I updated the code. I think I get why you were trying to use the `result.on'data')..` piece now. You can pass a callback to the `runCommand` function, which will be passed into the command's data callback. Now you can have multiple `runCommand`'s with separate callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more searching what I needed to do was create a custom event handler. Here's the example I came up with:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

runCommand = function (arg1,arg2) {
    var self = this;
    var cmd = spawn(arg1,arg2);
    cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        self.emit('updated', data);
    });
}
util.inherits(runCommand, events.EventEmitter);

var result = new runCommand('watch',['date +%s']);

result.on('updated', function(data) {
    console.log('command ran');
});
```